# Using makeline() function for more than 2 points in spatialite?

Tags: spatialite, linestring

Is it possible to use `makeline()` function to make linestring geometries in spatialite for connecting more than 2 sequence points?
Suppose I have four sequence points P1, P2, P3, P4. Or are there any other way to do this instead of using `makeline()`?

Answer (score 8):

You could, of course, do this with conversion via Well Known Text:

```
spatialite> SELECT AsText(GeomFromText("LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4, 1 3)"));
AsText(GeomFromText("LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4, 1 3)"))
LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4, 1 3)
```

However it is definitely possible to use `MakeLine()` with more than two points.

Apart from the obvious version that you know about already, there are two more ways to call the `MakeLine()` function. The first is to use a MultiPoint geometry (if you already had one, or can make one from what you have):

```
spatialite> SELECT AsText(MakeLine(GeomFromText("MULTIPOINT(1 2,3 4,1 3)"), 0));
LINESTRING(1 3, 3 4, 1 2)
spatialite> SELECT AsText(MakeLine(GeomFromText("MULTIPOINT(1 2,3 4,1 3)"), 1));
LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4, 1 3)
```

The last argument (0 in the first example, 1 in the second) turns on reversal of order. You usually want this set to 1 (not reorder).

The other option is to use the aggregate function form. Lets say you have a table of point geometries:

```
spatialite> CREATE TABLE somepoints (label);
spatialite> SELECT AddGeometryColumn('somepoints', 'geom', 0, 'POINT', 'XY');
1
spatialite> INSERT INTO somepoints VALUES('a', MakePoint(1,2));
spatialite> INSERT INTO somepoints VALUES('b', MakePoint(3,4));
spatialite> INSERT INTO somepoints VALUES('c', MakePoint(1,3));
```

Lets see what that looks like:

```
spatialite> .headers on
spatialite> SELECT label, AsText(geom) FROM somepoints;
label|AsText(geom)
a|POINT(1 2)
b|POINT(3 4)
c|POINT(1 3)
```

Now you can select points to turn into a linestring:

```
spatialite> SELECT AsText(MakeLine(geom)) FROM somepoints;
AsText(MakeLine(geom))
LINESTRING(1 2, 3 4, 1 3)
```

Note that the SELECT could have some condition (WHERE clause) so you can filter if that suits your needs.

Comment: By your clear guidance, finally I got it more than I expected before. thx @BrandHards.

Comment: Perhaps you could mark this as "the answer" if it meets your needs.